# Can something go wrong if I choose not to virtualize even though I was told to do it?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy, virtualization

Sorry if this question is too stupid but I can't find an answer to it.
I'm a beginner in terms of databases so I'm taking a course in Udacity. In the course, they tell us to install Vagrant and VirtualBox in order to run an ubuntu virtual machine to make the exercises of the course. The problem is that my pc is not working properly with that virtual machine running, so I decided not to virtualize and do the stuff in my "normal" programming environment (in the course we use flask, sqlite and sqlalchemy in order to create a website using a database, and in the next lesson they teach to build a web server that uses our database). Somewhere on the internet I read about virtual machines being useful to work in your computer without messing our computer's configuration up. My question is, can this happen? Or what does it mean to "mess the configuration up"? Is it possible to make an **important** mistake that will make me wish I had virtualized?

Comment: lol possible ... but improbable ... if the whole stack is flask sqlite and sqlalchemy you should be just fine i think ./.. some packages are easier to install on linux than windows is all ... and most real servers would be on a linux server,(but they wouldnt use sqlite...)

Comment: If you don't have other web-servers I don't think you'll do an huge mess. However, when you are learning something, IMHO, it's always convenient to work in a sandbox environment.

Comment: If your PC doesn't work well with virtual machine because of lack of resource you can always use a docker file, or install ubuntu on a new partition.

Comment: I would have a dedicated box.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn’t mess any configuration in your PC. The whole point of virtualizing your programming environment is for security reasons, or because developing is easier on a Linux machine. If you’re going to do sql exercises, the worst you can possibly do is mess the database.

Comment: @gvgramazio I know, but I think those are the two most important points for a programming environment. Of course you have advantages like cloning, making backups the easy way, distribute services in different machines...

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think so.

VM is useful here in two ways: first, it teaches you to work with DB as with remote server, like in real world.

Second: it prevents your main OS from junking up. It’s not a big problem now, but windows can slow down due to many applications leaving junk in registry or whatever... I think it was mostly dealt with in win7, but was on Mac by that time.

You are probably fine, just don’t use `shutil.rmtree()` on C:\ ;)